# Applying scopes in joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, finder

I have following models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  default_scope where(:enabled => true, :out_of_stock => false)
  scope :enabled, where(:enabled => true)
  scope :out_of_stock, where(:out_of_stock => true)
end

class Item < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I've faced following code duplication, repeating scope conditions across entire project, when using joins:

```
Category.joins(:offers).where(:items => {:merchant_id => @merchant.id, :enabled => true, :out_of_stock => false})
```

It would be nice, if applying specified scope in joins will be possible:

```
Category.joins(:offers).where(:items => {:merchant_id => @merchant.id, :scope => :default})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `&` like this:

```
Category.joins(:offers, :items) & Item.default.where(:merchant_id => @merchant.id)
```

I think this is called interpolation. It joins the two queries together, preserving the first one as the *base* (it return `Category` objects).